# Eclipse badge notification

Tags: eclipse

[image: my situation]

Is there any way I can get rid of the badge notification? I'm using a Ventura 13.0 MacBook pro.

I tried everything but there is no Eclipse in the mac system settings notification options...

Comment: It may not be a notification, programs can set that text directly. Is that your workspace name or something like that? Possibly something in the "Workspace" page of the Preferences.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to disable the badge notification under the Workspace dialog.

1. Eclipse -> Preferences
2. Click General -> Workspace
3. Clear the "Show workspace name:" checkbox
4. Apply and Close

[image: Clear the badge notification on Eclipse running on MacOS]